NGINX Configuration issue when serving static assets
I want to serve a vue application using nginx which is getting requests from a loadbalancer nginx.
My load balancer nginx configuration
  server_name subdomain.domain.com;

  location /production/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.62;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # Handle Web Socket Connections
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

}

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://1944298_app/;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # Handle Web Socket Connections
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    
    # Error handling by Ashwin
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
}

I want to forward all https://subdomain.domain.com/production/* to frontend servers at 10.0.0.62 while all other requests goto my other backend servers.
The backend servers are working fine and correctly receiving all requests except production/*
In my frontend server(10.0.0.62) i have my vue application files at /home/forge/subdomain.domain.com/dist . so my nginx configuration in that server is
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name subdomain.domain.com;
server_tokens off;
root /home/forge/subdomain.domain.com/dist;
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

index index.html index.htm index.php;

location / {
   root /home/forge/subdomain.domain.com/dist;
   #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}

}

Now the problem is index.html in dist folder is getting served for all files(even for css/js). When i try https://subdomain.domain.com/production/js/test.js or https://subdomain.domain.com/production/css/index.css, the content coming is that of https://subdomain.domain.com/production/index.html(/home/forge/subdomain.domain.com/dist/index.html)
How can I fix this? Which server configuration needs fixing?
